# React Native Own font doesnt get applied to all elements

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I wanted to implement my own font (from google) to use it inside my app. I loaded it and it works because some text gets changed by it. However some text doenst change which doesnt make sense to me.

I guess its a bug somehow maybe somebody has experienced this. Its a simple screen with simple code.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';
import COLORS from '../assets/COLORS';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

class BMI extends Component {
  render() {

const BMI = 20;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}> BMI - Calculator </Text>

    <Text style={{color: COLORS.white, fontSize: 20}} >Dein momentaner BMI:  <Text style={{color: COLORS.primary, fontSize: 24}} >{BMI}</Text> </Text>

        <View>
          <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.inputText}>AGE</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.inputText}>HEIGHT</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.inputText}>WEIGHT</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.TextInput} />
          </View>
          <View style={{marginTop: 25, marginHorizontal: 15}}>
              <Button onPress={() => alert("Hello")} title="Calculate" color={COLORS.lightB} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    // justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: COLORS.darkBG,
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: COLORS.lightB,
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginVertical: 30,
    fontFamily: "Pacifico"
  },
  InputContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  inputText: {
    color: COLORS.white,
    width: '30%',
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontFamily: "Pacifico"
  },
  TextInput: {
    backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
    width: '60%',
    color: COLORS.white,
    fontFamily: "Pacifico"
  },
});

export default BMI;
```

As u can see I load pacifico and it works but only for this text ( see pic below ):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try to remove `fontWeight: 'bold'` from the textStyle object (may be this style doesn't work with bold fontWeight.

Comment: yeah thats it so simple lol :D ty